# C# Nested Loop for inserting multiples into DB

Tags: c#, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

I have an application used for warehousing furniture.  If the user enters a line with a qty > 1, I have a simple while loop where the line is broken out to be many unique lines inserted into a SQL db.  I.e.
Item chair  Qty 3

Becomes

```
Item    |Qty|Unique Key
Chair   |1  |1234
Chair   |1  |1235
Chair   |1  |1236
```

--

```
 while (Qty >= 1)
        {

            //Go Get Next Num
            // GetNextNum("LN");
            int NextNum = GetNextNum("LN");  //Method to get next number from DB table
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FurnitureDB"].ConnectionString;
            conn.ConnectionString = connStr;
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            //SQL Parameter List here

            cmd.CommandText = "InsertSODtl";

            SqlDataReader datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            Qty--;
        }
```

My challenge is, there are some items that have a multiplier, where one item will be in 3 pieces.  In which case I append a number behind the unique key:

```
Item Table  -  Qty 1 - Unique Key
------------------------------------
Table      | 1       | 1234
Table      | 1       | 12341
Table      | 1       | 12342
```

So I need a nested while loop/for loop or some method to insert the appropriate number of pieces.  So a table for example - there could be 2 tables, each with 3 pieces.  So I need to

```
Item Table  -  Qty 1 - Unique Key
------------------------------------
Table      | 1       | 1234
Table      | 1       | 12341
Table      | 1       | 12342
Table      | 1       | 1235
Table      | 1       | 12351
Table      | 1       | 12352
```

I'm struggling to come up with the logic to do this correctly.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: How do you know if an item has more than 1 piece? Is this stored in a table somewhere? Also the UniqueKey i am assuming that isnt auto-generated? Finally dont use `cmd.ExecuteReader();` for the insert unless you need to read back the results of the stored procedurect use `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Comment: It is stored in a DB.  The user enters the item detail info, and one of those pieces of info is a dropdown for "Item Classification".  There is an item classification table that contains a "number of pieces" value.  Unique key is not autogenerated, I have a next number table where I go look up the next number.  Thanks for the tip on executenonquery.

Comment: ...uh, appending on the "unique key" breaks good normalization practices.  And has the potential to break in all sorts of other fun ways too (ie, what happens after key `12340` is issued?).  Are you able to add a "part" or "piece" column or something?  Also, my intuition tells me your method to get the next number available is probably something like `SELECT MAX(...)`, which breaks in the face of concurrent use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option I would look at is doing this all from within the stored procedure to limit the queries you need to execute. This can be really easily achieved using any type of for loop in SQL. Now i have a basic table setup as below.

ItemTable

```
Item      | nvarchar(50)
Qty       | int
UniqueKey | int
```

ItemClassification

```
Item           | nvarchar(50) 
NumberOfPieces | int
```

Then a simple stored procedure such as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertSODtl]
    @item nvarchar(50),
    @uniqueKey int
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @pieces int = (SELECT TOP 1 NumberOfPieces FROM ItemClassification WHERE Item = @item)

    INSERT INTO ItemTable (Item, Quantity, UniqueKey) VALUES (@item, 1, @uniqueKey)

    IF @pieces IS NOT NULL AND @pieces > 1
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @count int = 1;
            WHILE @count < @pieces -- < assures we end -1 max piece count
                BEGIN 
                    INSERT INTO ItemTable VALUES (@item, 1, CAST(CAST(@uniqueKey as nvarchar(10)) + CAST(@count as nvarchar(5)) as int))
                    SET @count = @count + 1
                END
        END
END
```

Like I said it is pretty basic and probably not exactly how your tables look but the concept is there.

First query the amount of pieces in the `ItemClassification` table for the Item type (simple string).

Next insert the record into the `ItemTable`

Finally if `@pieces` is not null and `@pieces > 1` then we run a loop from `1 to @pieces - 1` inserting back into the `ItemTable` appending the value to the unique key. Now we have to cast the `@uniqueKey` and `@count` as string (`nvarchar(10)`) as we need to concat the values and not add them together.

Again a pretty basic example but limits the required queries.

This also doesnt require a change to your code and can be done in one query.

Example Use:

```
EXEC InsertSODtl 'Table', 1234
EXEC InsertSODtl 'Table', 1235
EXEC InsertSODtl 'Chair', 1236
```

Results in:

[image: ItemTable]
[image: ItemClassification]

Comment: I like this idea. I'll give this a try tonight and send an update. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This worked very well.  Thanks again for the suggestion.